# linux Email server stop working and saying there is no memory

Tags: linux, email-server

second day at a new company using a linux email sever, restarted the server due to errors and now then server is telling me it's full and wont reboot at all, is their any possibility I can free some hard drive space while the machine is booting up?

I know it's not very well described but there was no documentation left on the server as the guy who put it together is a plonka

Comment: I suggest you boot a live system and free some space from there. My guess is, that it needs space to write into the /var directory. Find out what harddisk/partition /var resides on, mount it and carefully free some space. E.g., by deleting old logs.

Comment: Called in a linux expert from london and turns out that the whole system has corrupted its self. System system consists of 3 different machines all running different version of linux. We have decide to purchase a new server and will be running up different quotes. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a bootable Linux disk and then having the machine boot from the disk instead of from the default hard drive (how this is done depends on the manufacturer and the BIOS, but usually it is done by keeping a key pressed while the computer is starting up and then selecting the CD drive).

Once you've booted Linux from the disk, you can access your hard-drive and delete some files on it to free up the space needed. Then, you can remove the disk and reboot the computer normally. One boot disk that I would recommend is [KNOPPIX](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html) - it supports plenty of hardware, so it is usually the most hassle-free to run, and has some useful built in software as well.

You can download the boot disk from [one of the mirrors](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix-mirrors/index-en.html), and then burn it to a CD for use. If you're having trouble getting it to work, there's more detailed instructions on [knoppix.net](http://www.knoppix.net/).